# Cannot set up port proxy with NodeJS, React, Apache, and LetsEncrypt

Tags: apache-2.4, node.js, lets-encrypt

I've got the following server setup (Ubuntu 19.04):

- NodeJS (Express) backend on port 3333
- React frontend in `/var/www/example.com`
- Apache with LetsEncrypt and automatic http > https redirect

I'm trying to force all requests from `example.com/api/*` to the NodeJS backend on port 3333. This is my `sites-enabled/example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /api https://127.0.0.1:3333/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://127.0.0.1:3333/api
</VirtualHost>
```

If it helps, this is my `sites-enabled/example.com-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin support@exampl
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

With this config:

- Requests to https://example.com/api/test give me the React Router 404 page and a 404 error in `access.log`
- Requests to http://example.com/api/test give me a 500 error

**How do I get the frontend to correctly proxy/redirect `example.com/api/*` requests to the NodeJS backend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting all http requests to https, but your proxy directives are in the http virtualhost.

Move the proxy* directives to the HTTPS virtualhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin support@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /api https://127.0.0.1:3333/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://127.0.0.1:3333/api
</VirtualHost>
```

On a side note, set `ProxyRequests` to `off`. This doesn't disable the ProxyPass directives, but enabling this turns your server into an open proxy. Usually you don't want this.

Regarding the 500 error, read your error log.

Comment: That did it, thank you so much, along with fixing an error NodeJS was throwing!